# DOM traversal in implementations of javascript getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, dom, tree-traversal

What method(s) of DOM (tree) traversal do implementations of the javascript function *getElementsByTagName* use? I ask because I'd like to be sure that the array returned by *getElementsByTagName* contains DOM elements in an order roughly from the top of the document to the bottom, which would be the case in a depth-first search of the DOM tree, for instance.

Comment: For some reason, i always was under the assumption of a BFS algorithm for that.  If you are worried about the order, i feel you might need to apply some additional conditions to your algorithm to speed it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out stuff like this by reading the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1938918D)

> **getElementsByTagName**
>
> Returns a NodeList of all descendant Elements with a given tag name,
>   **in the order in which they are encountered in a preorder traversal of this Element tree**.

Comment: @celeritas - no problem, if you don't need the nodeList to be live, querySelectorAll actually has better support in IE.